# Twin paradox with communication

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, time-dilation

Professor Brian Greene covers a unique angle into the twin paradox by having the stationary observer and the rocket release light beams towards each other in fixed intervals according to their proper time.

Here is a screen grab from a demonstration from his course at [World Science U](https://worldscienceu.com/courses/special-relativity-world-science-u/):[image]

Have any experiments been carried out to replicate what has been shown here?

Comment: What is show makes sense, and does not contradict the theory.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about here, an experiment showing what specifically?

Comment: @Triatticus Whether this exact asymmetry has been observed; the rapid incoming signals on the inbound journey of the rocket as well as any other observations.

Comment: @KurtG. Definitely, but I wanted to see if anyone has tried to replicate this effect.

Comment: The closest to this experiment is the famous [Hafele Keating experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment). To replicate Brian Greene's exact (?) asymmetry we have to (instantly ?) accelerate a rocket to 0.9c ? And instantly revert its direction? Even if you are happy with a smaller velocity: good luck.